# Isuue in installing android app in emulator

Tags: android, installation, emulation

I have an small android app. It size is 3.59MB. But when I install this app in the emulator it seems it's size is 452MB. Why this is happening?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced similar issue and also noticed it while developing android application. The android application sizes always varies devices to devices and in different emulators. Its because of the Memory availability in different devices and operating systems. So it will be vary from different device to device. Its not an issue actually its behavior of operating system and memory of the device.

Comment: No, you can not fix the size of an application. AFAIK there is no such property available to fix the size of an application from manifest.

Comment: But it's really a problem.Firstly I can run the application.But when I run it over and over logcat says there's no enough space on device.So I have to install and uninstall again and again.Then what should I do?

Comment: You need to increase the memory size of your emulator. OR you can install your application on device's internal memory by defining in your manifest `<application android:installLocation="internalOnly">` which will install application in internal memory of device.